# How would I be able to create this kind of set / collection in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a hard time Googling this because "set" usually returns results for things like "set object = nothing" which is not what I am looking for.

I am trying to create an object that will allow me to collect all unique occurrences of values across two columns, sorted by A and then B. For example:

```
Column A Column B

USA      Michigan
USA      Alabama
USA      Alabama
USA      Alabama
Canada   Quebec
```

I'd want an object that holds the values `(Canada, Quebec), (USA, Alabama), (USA, Michigan)` in this order (A is alphabetical, and then within each A, sort B alphabetically).

However I am at a complete loss for how to do this. At first I thought I needed a dictionary object, but this wasn't quite right for what I was going for. And then I thought maybe a Collection was needed, but this didn't seem to be quite right, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a *Collection* like:

```
Sub Collectables()
    Dim c As Collection, N As Long
    Set c = New Collection
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To N
        t = Cells(i, 1).Value & ", " & Cells(i, 2).Value
        ky = CStr(t)
        c.Add t, ky
    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox c.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried something similar at one point but it doesn't keep values uniquely -- if you add the same item multiple times, you get multiple entries. In a set, even if you add the same item many times, you correctly only have one entry for it in the set.

Comment: @MyNameIsKhan the **key** is to use a key

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Is there a way to sort the collection? Or check if t,ky already exists in c? (i.e. not using the on error resume next thing)

Comment: quick update: I decided to use a simple bubble sort, and that seemed to work. My only question now is about removing the error thing

Comment: @MyNameIsKhan   **Do Not** remove the error thing.......its the *error thing* that removes the duplicates!!

Comment: I know, was just curious if there was another way to do it that didn't involve relying on error-catching. I placed the checker in its own function to limit that error catch to its own scope, seems to work.

Comment: @MyNameIsKhan  There are at least **2** other methods....one involves *Advanced Filtering* and the other involves using the *RemoveDuplicates* method of the Range object.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, shouldn't `t = Cells(i, 1).Value & ", " & Cells(i, 1).Value` be `t = Cells(i, 1).Value & ", " & Cells(i, 2).Value` ?